# T- SQL code to access at least three tables to get information

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. The first table is called `f_CellphoneSubscribers` and the columns are:

- subscribers
- CountryId
- Urban Population
- Year
- SubscribersPerUrbanDweller

The second table is `d_Country` and columns are:

- CountryId
- CountryCode
- Name
- Continent
- Region

What T-SQL code should I use to answer the following question:

1. What is the first country to have more than 20,000 cell phone
   subscribers? Display this country along with the year it exceeded this
   threshold and the country’s population density at that time.
2. In which year did the number of cell phone subscriptions in Canada first exceed those in Finland? Display the year and the countries' respective subscription numbers. Parameterize your query so comparable results could be found for any 2 countries.
3. Looking specifically at countries in North America, show the year over year growth in cell phone subscribers from 2000 to 2005 expressed as the per capita change from the prior year.

Comment: You list four data points but say you have three tables.   What is the table structure for those three tables?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can show some things you have already tried that didn't work, you are more likely to get help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Join

A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

Example:

```
SELECT Country.Name, Subscriber.NumOfSubscriber
FROM Country
INNER JOIN Subscriber ON Country.CountryID=Subscriber.CountryID
WHERE Subscriber.NumOfSubscriber > 20000;
```

This example has been simplified to show how to join 2 tables.

Extend it to join 3 tables, with ordering.

Comment: The quiz contains only 2 tables and I have posted the question again.Thanks